# Computing a series in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a recursive method to compute a series in java 1/i.

Here is my code:

```
public static double computeSeries(int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (1/n) + computeSeries(n - 1);

}
```

where 'n' is passed through the main method.  However it doesn't exactly work correctly.  FE when I type in 3, it returns 2.0, where I calculated it to be 1.8, and if I use 2, it gives me 1.0

Comment: Hint: See what the result of `1/n` is for `int n` vs. `double n`.

Answer (score 4):

While you're going to work with decimals, you might at least want to have a `double` as input

---

### Solution

```
public static double computeSeries(double n)
```

However, if you only want the method to have an `int` as input, you might want to change `1/n` to `1.0/n` this will result to an operation of type `double` instead of `int`

This is called [Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

---

### [JLS §5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)

> If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.

Comment: I'm honestly kicking myself in the nuts RN over stressing so much over this.  But thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

First part of your result (1/n) is truncated to an int:

```
    return (1/n) + computeSeries(n - 1);
```

Force calculations to be done in a double type by changing 1 to 1.0 (then it's a double):

```
    return (1.0/n) + computeSeries(n - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1/n
```

You are calculating in integers.  This is always ZERO unless n == 1

Answer (score 0):

Your first division will be `0` in most of the cases, since you're calculating with integers.

Instead use one of

- `return (1.0 / n) + computeSeries(n - 1);`
- `return (1 / (double) n) + computeSeries(n - 1);`
- `public static double computeSeries(double n) {`

Bonus: You should take care of `n = 0` to prevent a `java.lang.ArithmeticException`.

Answer (score 0):

As most others have said, you need to convert the values to `double` before performing operations. Also, and this may just be personal preference, you may not want to have `n` calls of `computeSeries` running before they can all be completed.

Edit: After thinking more, using the for loop as I did below, there is no need for an extra method to calculate each term in the series. You can simply do the following

```
public static double computeSeries(int n) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        sum += (1.0/(double)i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```